# Specifying a one-to-many relationship using a different foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Not sure if the title is good enough, but I'm going to try to explain the problem I'm encountering. For the record, I'm very new to Code-First and Fluent API, and this is the first production project I'm using them in.

Basically, the web-app I'm trying to create is multi-lingual, and I decided to have a table with the following fields (I added comments to explain what I'm trying to achieve):

```
public class Content
{
    [Key]
    // Required Key.
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    // Language (another class that stores culture and other culture specific info).
    public Language Language { get; set; }

    [Required]
    // Text for the current field.
    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    // The field Id, this stores what field the text above relates to.
    // So if I have a field "Welcome", and the website has 5 languages, I'll have 5 entries with the same GUID
    // but with different text and different language.
    public virtual Guid FieldId { get; set; }
}
```

I have been trying many solutions, but I haven't managed to create what I want. My latest one is:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Key]
    public Guid TitleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("TitleId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Key]
    public Guid DescriptionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Description { get; set; }
```

and this in context (not sure if it makes sense):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Winning>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Description)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.MapKey("DescriptionId", "FieldId")
            .MapKey("TitleId", "FieldId");
    });
```

Basically what I want is that when I load the object above, through that GUID, I get a list of relating text (preferably just one, as I'd filter by culture), the table *Content* will be used by other object so a foreign key within *Content* does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm.. where to start. :)

you don't need to have the ID of the Object and the Object both mapped.  In fact EF won't like this.

Just something like this will get you the code first mapping that you want:

<del>[Required]
    [Key]
    public Guid DescriptionId { get; set; }</del>

```
[Required]
public virtual ICollection<Content> Description { get; set; }
```

The fluent mapping you are trying to use is for many to many relationships.  You only need to specify fluent mappings if the code first migration doesn't work, or if you want to specify your own column or table names.  Once you remove your double mappings you probably won't need to specify anything special in fluent.  Code first will just figure out what the column need to be and create them for you (unless you are working with an existing DB).  IF you find you still need fluent make sure you are using the correct mapping.

Lastly I don't think you can solve your problem using mappings.  Map your entities so that the relate together.  Not sure what your second entity is named but here goes...

Winning has a collection of Titles and Descriptions?  Then when you are displaying this information on a page you just need to use some code/logic in your controller to decide which title and description you will use in your view based on the current conditions of your application.  Maybe you have something in your controller method to say what language you need etc.

Hope that gets you back on the right track.

Comment: RE: DescriptionId & TitleId, understandable, I was trying to follow some tutorial I found online. If I just include the ICollection, it'll join with the Id, not the FieldId.

I need to join Description to Content via FieldId, not Id... not sure how that's done though...

Comment: In the code you posted description is of type content.  I'm pretty confused by your object model.  What is the class name of the second model that you listed in your example?

Comment: In that case it's Winning, I omitted it because it can be anything, content is just a piece of text that is bound to a language and to a field.

Comment: Okay so you want it so that the GUID in FieldId either specifies that it's a title on winning, or a description on winning or some other field on some other object?  Is that right?

Comment: Seems to me like you are still going to need some kind of foreign key.  How else will you know which winning object your content goes with.  You need to know which object, and which field.  And then you add to that, you don't even know what model the content connects to.  It could be a winning object or something else.  I don't think entity framework will be able to map this for you to automatically pull the data that you want.  I would remove the relationship between winning and content from your model and then utilize Linq to pull the content for your winning object manually.

Comment: This should be a simple one to many relationship but binding with a field other than the primary key. Let me try to make an example, imagine Winning has DescriptionID 123 and TitleID 124, Content has fieldID 123 and 5 translations, and another 5 translations for field 124. Another class called HelloWorld as TextID 125, Content has 5 translations of fieldID 125.

This way I can load HelloWorld, and the TextID will be a list of Content, which will load all 5 translations. Another option would be to filter by Language and load only 1 translation(but this is secondary). Winning object will have PK

Comment: How do you have a 1 to many without using primary/foreign keys? What you just described is different than what you have in your model. Does winning only have 1 description or many? You make it sound like you need another model for translation. Winning has 1 description (so winning table gets fk to description content). Description content has many translations.  Each translation would have a fk back to description content. In the model you have winning has multiple descriptions. That means that each description would need to have a reference back to which winning they are related to. 1 to many

Comment: with 1 to many the foreign key goes on the many side, so description would need to reference the PK of winning. if it was 1 to many.  Overall this all sounds like stuff entity framework can handle for you automatically.  You are trying to do too much.  Get your models right.  Generate your DB tables.  Rely on linq to pull the data you want.

Comment: Winning would have 1 Description with multiple translations. Therefore it would have multiple Content with the same FieldID (FK). I can't have WinningID in Content, cos content is used by other Classes. I'll try to create a diagram (probably tomorrow, I need to go out) of what I'm trying to achieve, it would be achievable had I been using EF (not code-first) so I'm guessing it is also achievable using code-first.

Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: Hi Ben, this is an extremely simple class/table [diagram](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1929707/Multilanguage.png). The aim is that getting a page will return a list of titles (which we can filter by culture) and a list of text which we can filter by culture. The same is true for Winnings and for other classes.

Schema wise this is attainable but since we chose to use code first we need to find a way of doing it using this technique.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Daryl, I think you have 2 options.  Change your model so that winning.description is 1 to 1 relationship, same with all other references to content.  Move your Translations 1 more level down in a separate model/table.  Content has 1 to many relationship with translations.  Each translation has fk back to content.  Then entity framework can reference content using keys, which is what it needs.  Or Forget about trying to get EF to recognize this relationship.  Add the GUIDs as properties to your models, then pull in the related data manually using linq.  Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll take the 2nd solution, saving the Guids and filtering by that Guid whenever I need the text.